# Ruby on Rails - Does attribute order matter in an ActiveModel:Serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have a simple Serializer where processing of an attribute depends on the processing of another attribute.

So my code looks something like:

```
class CounterSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attribute :CounterId do
    object.id
  end

  attribute :CounterValue do
    @value = SomeClass.get_counter_value(object.id)
  end

  attribute :NextCounterValue do
    @value + 1
  end
end
```

So, given that I use `@value` in two attributes, and the value of the second depends on the output of the first, can I assume that `CounterValue` will be computed **before** `NextCounterValue`? (i.e no async computation issues)

Also bear in mind that `NextCounterValue` should not make another call to `SomeClass.get_counter_value` (performance issues)

Comment: i guess so. usually attributes are displayed in the order specified in the serializer file. 
hence the computations will also be one by one ,in the order mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you code **should** work but if you want to be sure that your code will work i advise you to use [memoization](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/).

```
class CounterSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :counterId, :counterValue, :nextCounterValue

  def counterId
    object.id
  end

  def counterValue
    @value ||= SomeClass.get_counter_value(object.id)
  end

  def nextCounterValue
    counterValue + 1
  end
end
```

Thanks to memoization, this code will not make another call to `SomeClass.get_counter_value` and you will be sure that your code behaves like you want.